# How can one scrape a web page with jQuery and XPath?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpath, web-scraping

I can stick a jQuery javascript link in the header of a web page via Firebug. Then, I can run a script to scrape it and the pages it links to.

How do I begin writing this script in jQuery or javascript in general? Is there an interface in either jQuery/Javascript with which I can use XPath to access the elements on a page (and on the pages it links to)?

Answer (score 5):

First, you'll need a JavaScript runtime outside of the browser. The most common is Node.js. Next you'll need a way to create the DOM client-side. This is typically done using [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom).

So, your script should:

1. download the html page (`jsdom` does this for you, but you can use [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request))
2. create a client-side DOM
3. parse using jQuery

Here is a sample Node.js script:

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom");

jsdom.env("http://nodejs.org/dist/", [
    'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js'
  ], function(errors, window) {
  console.log("there have been", window.$("a").length, "nodejs releases!");
});
```

You would run it, like so:

```
$ node scrape.js
```

Don't forget to install `jsdom` first:

```
$ npm install --production jsdom
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the HTML of page quickly with:

```
var html = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
```

This will only return a string literal and it will not capture the root element.

Comment: Thanks, do you have an idea of how I can automatically scrape the pages it links to too?

Comment: Just iterate through the child `<a/>`s and then load the content of those pages as well.

Answer (score 3):

You might be interested in [pjscrape](http://nrabinowitz.github.com/pjscrape), a web-scraping library built for exactly this purpose (disclaimer: this is my project). It's based on [PhantomJS](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs), a headless Webkit implementation you can run from the command line, and it has a really simple syntax for scraping data from multiple pages and finding additional urls to spider and scrape.

Comment: Thank you. Your project sounds interesting. The reason I am using jQuery and Javascript is that the page I seek to scrape is login-protected. Do you think this will work?

Comment: You can definitely use PhantomJS for this, but there may not be a great way to do it with pjscrape yet - it depends on the login setup. Another option is to use Selenium, which actually runs in an open browser - this allows it to handle very complex login operations.